# Can I assign a Interface to a object field in TypeScript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have this object:

```
export class Section{
  singleLabel:string;
  pluralLabel:string;
  index:number;
  dataInterface:Interface;
}
```

My need is to assign to the field **dataInterface** an interface, because in some components/services I have to use the **Section** object to determine the type of Interface I have to pass to this method:

```
httpClient.get<section.dataInterface>(url);
```

This is one of the interface I should assign to the field **dataInterface**:

```
export interface Idata { 
  numeroPagina:number;
  numeroElementiPerPagina:number;
  numeroTotaleElementi:number;
}
```

I need to do something like this:

```
section.dataInterface = Idata;
httpClient.get<section.dataInterface>(url);
```

Is there a way to put an Interface inside an object field?
Thank you

Comment: you can assign interfaces to the keys like `dataInterface: DataInterface` where DataInterface is another interface in your code.

Comment: Hi @AmirSaleem, actually I already tried a solution like the one you suggested; maybe I did something wrong. Can you type the code please?

Comment: please mention both the interfaces in your question which you would like to link. I'll write the code then

Comment: Hi @AmirSaleem, I edited my post, I hope now it's clearer :)

Comment: Written the answer, hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The answer in no, you cannot use an interface as a value. Interfaces are not compiled to javascript and are not available on runtime:

> The interface contains only the declaration of the methods and fields, but not the implementation. We cannot use it to build anything.
>
> When the Typescript compiler compiles it into JavaScript, then the
> interface will be removed from the JavaScript file. Thus, its purpose
> is to help in the development stage only.

[link](https://www.javatpoint.com/typescript-class-vs-interface)

Comment: Thank you. What I was looking for was a trick to make an Object field "contain" an Interface type. Probably there are no tricks :)

Comment: Ok I get it, maybe you should come up with a different approach, a union for example!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, what you want to do is that you want to use a nested interface using interface. Here is the implementation. You can access nested interfaces using bracket notation.

```js
// type declarations
interface Idata {
    numeroPagina: number;
    numeroElementiPerPagina: number;
    numeroTotaleElementi: number;
}

interface ISection {
    singleLabel: string;
    pluralLabel: string;
    index: number;
    dataInterface: Idata;
}

//  implementation

httpClient.get<ISection["dataInterface"]>(url);

export class Section implements ISection {}
```

Comment: Thank you, but actually what I need is an Object with a field that contain a specific type of interface, in order to know what type of Interface a specific object is carrying, by doing something like this: let interface<Interface> = object.interfaceType; anyway thank you for your help, your answer is interesting an useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't mix types declarations with your code which is to be executed at runtime. As Typescript provides only compile-time support.

Comment: So, you can't use `let` to define a type or interface.